# How use enum in postgres

Tags: postgresql, enums

I have created an `enum` type in Postgres:

```
CREATE TYPE myenum AS ENUM ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

I have created a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.mystore(type myenum)
```

Now in the stored procedure how I can check if a type is `'a'` or `'b'` like

```
if(type = myenum.a or type =  myenum.b) then
   ...
end if;
```

In fact the last line of code is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IF (type = 'a' OR type = 'b') THEN
  ...
END IF;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `string literal`:

```
WHERE type = 'a' OR type = 'b'
```

Or:

```
WHERE type IN ('a', 'b')
```